# max row sequence from sorted list for each index

Tags: python, list, sequence

I have stored the input by index(a,b,c) and then in ascending order(by base sequence) as following:

```
input=['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', 'Ca', 'Da', '4b','5b', '6b', '7b', '7c', '8c']
```

the sequence of numbers in my base in ascending order is:

```
"123456789ABCD"
```

Now what i want to do is select items that are in a row of length more than 4 for each index(a,b,c) and add them to the output list (i.e. find maximum row sequence for each index(a,b,c), actually I need all row combinations that are more than 4 for each index, but I have an idea how to make combinations if i find the MAX LEN row sequence for each index(a,b,c))

so for input above the following output is expected:

```
[['3a','4a','5a','6a'],['4b','5b','6b','7b']]
```

here's the code I tried to use, code is in python:

```
input=['3a','4a','5a','6a','Ca','Da','4b','5b','6b','7b','7c','8c']
digits = '123456789ABCD'
digit_map = {d:i for i, d in enumerate(digits)}
matches=[]
temp=[]
prev = 789
print hands
for n in input:
    if digit_map[n[0]] == prev + 1:
        matches.append(n)
        print matches
    else:
        if len(matches) >= 4:
            temp.append(matches)
            print temp 
        matches = [n]
        print matches
    prev = digit_map[n[0]]
print temp
```

Comment: What does you current code (not) do?

Comment: @TimCastelijns it gives me only first sequence

Comment: Code works for sequences except the last one, if i have more than one sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst=['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', 'Ca', 'Da', '4b','5b', '6b', '7b', '7c', '8c']
prev = lst[0][-1]
streak = 1
streaklst = [lst[0]]
matches = []
for x in lst[1:]:
    if x[-1] == prev and streak < 4:
        streak += 1
        streaklst.append(x)
    else:
        if streak == 4:
            matches.append(streaklst)
        streaklst = [x]
        streak = 1
        prev = x[-1]

print(matches)
```

will print

```
[['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a'], ['4b', '5b', '6b', '7b']]
```

NOTE: for

```
lst=['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', 'Ca', 'Da', 'Aa', 'Ba', '4b','5b', '6b', '7b', '7c', '8c']
```

it will print

```
[['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a'], ['Ca', 'Da', 'Aa', 'Ba'], ['4b', '5b', '6b', '7b']]
```

i.e. it will find all streaks of 4. You need to tell us if you want that as your question is a little ambiguous in regards to whether you want the whole streak, cut the streak at length four or want all streaks of length four (or higher). At least to me, your sample output and what you are writing what you want to do differ.

To just find streaks longer than four and store them you can do:

```
lst=['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', 'Ca', 'Da', 'Aa', 'Ba', '4b','5b', '6b', '7b', '7c', '8c']
prev = lst[0][-1]
streak = 1
streaklst = [lst[0]]
matches = []
for x in lst[1:]:
    if x[-1] == prev:
        streak += 1
        streaklst.append(x)
    else:
        if streak >= 4:
            matches.append(streaklst)
        streaklst = [x]
        streak = 1
        prev = x[-1]

print(matches)
```

Which will print

```
[['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', 'Ca', 'Da', 'Aa', 'Ba'], ['4b', '5b', '6b', '7b']]
```

`len(matches)` will now give you the number of streaks >= 4.

Comment: actually its streak >=4, should i just change ==4 to >=4?, and what about Z and Y ? there are no numbers with values of Z and Y in my base

Comment: @MotherLand Z and Y were just examples to show you what would happen with a streak of eight. The code can easily be adjusted to your needs, you just need to tell us what exactly you want to do (see the last part of my post)

Comment: i need just max streak of 4+ for each index, (in assignment i have to find all of streak combinations of 4+, however its not so hard, i will run iteration 2ce for found streak: from beginning and end of streak until i reach len of 4, if length of streak is more than 4)

Comment: @MotherLand I added code to find all streaks >= 4 in my post, does that work for you?

Comment: @MotherLand It would be nice of you to accept one of the answers in this topic if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like inserting an extra loop? (this can be optimized further)

```
input=['3a','4a','5a','6a','Ca','Da','4b','5b','6b','7b','7c','8c']
digits = '123456789ABCD'
digit_map = {d:i for i, d in enumerate(digits)}
print hands
temp = []
for letter in ['a','b','c']:
    prev = 789
    matches=[]
    filtered = [i for i in input if i[1]==letter]
    for n in filtered:
        if digit_map[n[0]] == prev + 1:
            matches.append(n)
            print matches
        else:
            if len(matches) >= 4:
                temp.append(matches)
                print temp 
            matches = [n]
            print matches
        prev = digit_map[n[0]]
    print temp    
print temp
```

Comment: Strange, it works for this input, however still have same problem (last row sequence is not added to list in my code), should i put all of my code? Its a project so I'm a bit afraid some students from my course may find it. :)

Comment: I partially solved the issue, just put extra 'if len(matches) >= 4: temp.append(matches)' after the iteration done. But it is not the rational solution :(

Comment: I see. so you use temp as array-of-arrays, then it should not be cleared in the beginning of the outer iteration.